# whats going wrong? Awk output from a Temporary variable into BASH array

Tags: bash, awk

I declare a temporary file

```
    TEMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
```

Then I have an awk statement fill it with an output...
Next step, I have another AWK statement take out particular field to put into an array... this is 'crapping out'

```
DATES = ($(awk -F'/' '{print $2}' '${TEMPFILE}'))
```

I'm also parsing out into a separate array using a CUT (not sure if it's working either)

```
IPS = ($(cut -f2 $(TEMPFILE)))
```

I'm getting the error:

> Script12.sh: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> Script12.sh: line 36: `DATES = ($(awk -F'/' '{print $2}'
>   '${TEMPFILE}'))'*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is space-sensitive. The shell syntax for assignment is

```
var1=[word1] ...
```

where the [] indicates an optional part, and ... repetition.

Note: no blanks around the `=` sign.

Then, there is no **parameter expansion** (replacing `$var` with its value) inside single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
DATES=($(awk -F/ '{print $2}' "${TEMPFILE}"))
```

Comment: Note that while spaces are forbidden around the `=` in an assignment, they're required in a test. E.g. `if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]` does what you expect, while `if [ "$foo"="$bar" ]` does something completely different (and useless). And `if ["$foo"="$bar"]` will get you a command not found error...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use blanks for variable assignment in BASH. There should be no blanks around the `=` sign

Comment: @TimEagle I'd like to. But Jens has made it much clearer than me. I thus voted hime up :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't put spaces around assignments in shell and you need to change single to double quotes around your shell variable when used in your awk command line, i.e. `"$TEMPFILE"` not `'${TEMPFILE}'` and then not try to execute that variable on your cut command line (think about what `$(TEMPFILE)` means).